# linux & c - access file on disk.. by address?

Tags: c, linux, file

Is it possible to get to a file by address in a c program or in a terminal (linux)? I know it sounds odd, to me either actually, but I am just experimenting.

For example, replace

```
FILE * f = fopen("myfile.txt","r")
```

by something absolutely stunning like

```
int fd = open(&0x545f6f5,"r")
```

or echo &0x545f6f5 that would grab the part of the concerned file (would need a length so more like echo &0x545f6f5 20 to read the 20 bytes next to the address)?

I know about mmap, but again, my question is much more something like experimentation.

Well, the overall picture is: can one access any part of a file on the linux filesystem with an address (and ideally a length)?

### UPDATE:

Say my partition id /dev/sda1 and i want to access the raw memory value (readable or not) with an address and not a name.
If I seek for address &0x545f6f5 and that it happens to be myfile.txt at an offset of say 64, i would read the byte at this position. I hope it makes it clearer :)

Comment: This doesn't make sense until you define what you mean by an address - what is 0x545f6f5 suppsed to mean ? A memory address ? A byte offset within a file ? A physical location on the hard drive ?

Comment: I think you need to read up on how hard drives and file systems work.  Check out http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cylinder-head-sector.

Comment: @seanmk CHS addressing is not used anymore today. Hard disks use LBA-addressing today and Linux abstracts away these differences for you if you were to use a CHS based disk.

Comment: What problem would be solved if such a feature did exist?

Comment: @jxh : It doesn't solve a problem per se, but it is just playing with the system, and test new possibilities

Comment: @nos : you are right, sorry : I updated the post.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's say `myfile.txt` is on the `ext3` filesystem mounted at `/`, and that filesystem is on the partition `/dev/sda1`. You could conceivably open the device `/dev/sda1` (the partition) or `/dev/sda` (the entire drive) and access the file's bytes if you knew its offset on disk.

For example, if you somehow determined that the file's contents were at offset `0xDEADBEEF` on the first partition of the first hard drive, you could do:

```
int fd = open("/dev/sda1", O_RDONLY);
lseek(fd, 0xDEADBEEF, SEEK_SET);
read(fd, buffer, 20);
```

Accessing the raw device this way bypasses the filesystem. Filesystems are where file metadata is stored, such as their names, locations, and sizes. If you poked around the beginning of `/dev/sda1` you could conceivably read the raw filesystem data yourself rather than relying on the kernel filesystem drivers to do it for you.

Comment: It should be noted that using an OS library is probably an easier route.

Comment: Please notice that doing IO on device files with a file system in them, especially when that file system is mounted bears some risk. Please do not attempt to write into a file system that is currently mounted, you may cause data loss.

Comment: @SevenBits I don't see an easier route than basic system calls like `open()`, `read()`, `write()`, and `lseek()`.

Comment: Yes, I was talking about /dev/sda1 for example, the root of the partition

Comment: @FUZxxl That's why I said that using an OS library is an easier route - you don't have to worry about potential problems caused by writing a mounted file system.