# linux - Do the filesystem allow to make blackholes?

Tags: c, linux, file, text, filesystems

## Context

I just asked a question here :[my former question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25916345/linux-c-access-file-on-disk-by-address/25916520#25916520)
It leads to another question.

#### I read so much kernel code these times that it wrangles my head.

## Question :

Is it possible to point to another part of the filesystem just like a hardlink would, without taking more space ?
Let me explain : could an address on disk points to another one but without taking the space of a pointer. it is the principle of hard link. But it would be applied to a part of a file for example.

The overall picture is to create a file composed of multiple other files. I know about named pipes but it seems that it does not fulfill the goal : it is blocking and you have to permanently read it.

Thanks a lot

### Update:

Is it possible to theoretically corrupt/hack the kernel to fulfill that goal ?

Comment: No possible in general unless in a corrupted file system. Wikipage about [Ext2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext2) has a nice picture

Comment: Do you mean block-level data deduplication?

Comment: @5gon12eder:hmm yes possible, will look into it :)

Comment: @Basile : updated the question accordingly

Comment: See also: http://askubuntu.com/questions/149152/block-level-deduplicating-filesystem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, you cannot do that (unless you patch a lot the kernel to add new system calls), since your thing don't fit into existing Posix file definition and API.

I guess also you should not do that, and instead use some *user-level* library for indexed files (like [gdbm](http://www.gnu.org.ua/software/gdbm/)), or use [Sqlite](http://sqlite.org/), or even some [database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database) ([relational](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database_management_system) ones like [PostGreSQL](http://postgresql.org/) or [MariaDB](http://mariadb.org/), [NoSQL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL) ones like [mongodb](http://www.mongodb.org/) etc...)

You could also play with [FUSE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_in_Userspace) e.g. to interface as a file system some more complex data (e.g. some database). See also [VFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_file_system)

BTW, there is no point in doing such complex things inside the kernel. Disk I/O is slow, and the overhead of going to userland is negligible.

And [extended file attributes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_file_attributes) is also a way to add more [meta-] data to files.

Comment: btrfs supports deduplication: https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Deduplication

Answer (score 1):

Some filesystems do, most notably btrfs, which is a COW filesystem, so making a copy of a file, and overwriting a little part of it should end up with two files which share most data.

Deduplicating blocks after the fact requires some additional support, e.g: comparing hashes of disk blocks (either when writing to disk, or offline, to deduplicate existing file blocks).

Note that this is done at the block level, so to create a file "composed" of other files (in reality, pointing to the same blocks as other files), the identical parts should be multiple-of-block-size–sized and block-size–aligned.